# Alt+Tab doesn't work correctly

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I re-installed my Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop with Windows XP, but on installation I realized that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work correctly. It shows me the display of the windows that I can switch between:

[image: alt-tab oic]

but it doesn't go to the window that I select.

Also if I have more than 4-5 windows open it doesn't move the selection to the last 2.

How can I solve this without re-installing the computer again? I have already installed a lot of software and ideally hope to solve this problem without another re-installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either get a hot-key creator program and create a hot-key for it, or you could re-install the Dell driver software. I had the same problem with my Dell Inspiron 1545

Comment: which driver did u have to reinstall? seems like it could have been a driver issue? Could you post some links of a hot-key creator program?

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Powertoy alt-tab replacement is good; and better than the 'standard' one with windows; but I prefer TaskSwitchXP.

*TaskSwitchXP is an advanced task management utility that picks up where the standard Windows Alt+Tab switcher leaves off. It provides the same functionality, and adds visual styles to the dialog and also enhances it by displaying thumbnail preview of the application that will be switched to*

[TaskSwitchXP](http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp.html)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search using Google I found [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-55086_35_0.html) thread on tomshardware. As you want to avoid a complete reinstall you could just try the powertoys <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> replacement available [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/TaskswitchPowertoySetup.exe).

Comment: Haven't tried out the powertoy as i thought it would lead to further issues, though i will look into one of the solutions i.e. of registry editing that was provided in the link that u pointed to.